# C# не удаеться создать .ini файл

Tags: c#

Для записи данных создаю .ini файл, на своем ПК код работает, пробую запустить программу на другом ПК, файл не создаеться, никаких ошибок при этом не получаю.

Код:

```
   SetIni setIni = new SetIni(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\setting\Projects\" + "test" + ".ini");
        setIni.INI_write("project", "test", "test");
```

SetIni.cs

```
 class SetIni
{
    public static  string way;
    INIManager manager;
    public SetIni(string way)
    {
        SetIni.way =  way;
        manager = new INIManager(way);

    }

    // Создание объекта, для работы с файлом

    public void INI_write(string section,
                           string key,
                           string value)
    {

        //Записать значение по ключу age в секции main
        manager.WritePrivateString(section, key, value);

        //Получить значение по ключу name из секции main

    }

    public string INI_read(string section,
                           string key)
    {
        //Получить значение по ключу name из секции main
        string name = manager.GetPrivateString(section, key);
       
        return name;
    }

}

//Класс для чтения/записи INI-файлов
public class INIManager
{
    //Конструктор, принимающий путь к INI-файлу
    public INIManager(string aPath)
    {
        path = aPath;
    }

    //Конструктор без аргументов (путь к INI-файлу нужно будет задать отдельно)
    public INIManager() : this("") { }

    //Возвращает значение из INI-файла (по указанным секции и ключу) 
    public string GetPrivateString(string aSection, string aKey)
    {
        //Для получения значения
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(SIZE);

        //Получить значение в buffer
        GetPrivateString(aSection, aKey, null, buffer, SIZE, path);

        //Вернуть полученное значение
        return buffer.ToString();
    }

    //Пишет значение в INI-файл (по указанным секции и ключу) 
    public void WritePrivateString(string aSection, string aKey, string aValue)
    {
        //Записать значение в INI-файл
        WritePrivateString(aSection, aKey, aValue, path);
    }

    //Возвращает или устанавливает путь к INI файлу
    public string Path { get { return path; } set { path = value; } }

    //Поля класса
    private const int SIZE = 1024; //Максимальный размер (для чтения значения из файла)
    private string path = null; //Для хранения пути к INI-файлу

    //Импорт функции GetPrivateProfileString (для чтения значений) из библиотеки kernel32.dll
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetPrivateProfileString")]
    private static extern int GetPrivateString(string section, string key, string def, StringBuilder buffer, int size, string path);

    //Импорт функции WritePrivateProfileString (для записи значений) из библиотеки kernel32.dll
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "WritePrivateProfileString")]
    private static extern int WritePrivateString(string section, string key, string str, string path);
}
```

Путь

> Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\setting\Projects\

существует, не могу понять в чем еще может быть проблема.

Спасибо

Comment: А где проверки на ошибки?

Comment: 1. `Environment.CurrentDirectory` - это рабочая директория, другими словами, если вы допустим запустите `cmd` и там пропишете `полный\путь\до\файла\файл.exe`, то рабочей директорией будет у вас то, в каком каталоге сейчас консоль (обычно это директория пользователя), либо вы можете изменить ее через ярлык к вашему приложению. Другими словами, ваш путь может быть не тем, что вы ожидаете, выведите его на экран и посмотрите то там или нет. 2. Для создания пути лучше использовать `Path.Combine()` (`Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"setting\Projects", "test.ini")`).

Comment: @mik.ov, заворачивал код в try{}catch(Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
Ошибок не выводилось

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Понимаю все риски использования Environment.CurrentDirectory.
Попробовал вручную создать файл в директории Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\setting\Projects\" + "test" + ".ini"

На своем ПК  программа просто дозаписала файл, на другом ПК никаких действий не произошло

Comment: Повторюсь, выведите куда либо ваш путь и посмотрите как на одном компьютере, так и на другом, точно там то место, где вы ожидаете данный файл?

Comment: EvgeniyZ, да, вывожу путь в textbox, копирую его оттуда и в обеих случаях через проводник файл открывается.

Частично понял, проблема в кодировке, C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Папка\Debug\setting\Projects - не работает

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Debug\setting\Projects - работает

Comment: OS везде Windows?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, да, и там и там win 10,проблема в кодировке, убрал кирилицу из пути - теперь файл создается и данные в него записываются, но если в файл записывать кирилицу - будут крякозябры

Comment: Прочитайте документацию к функциям которые вы импортируете . Проверяйте значения которые они возвращают, вызывайте Marshall.GetLastWin32Error()

Comment: `[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "WritePrivateProfileString", Charset = Charset.Unicode)]` https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.charset?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @aepot, спасибо, помогло!
Всем спасибо за ответы